# System.TypeLoadException: Parent class vtable failed to initialize, due to: VTable setup of type AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, material-components-android

**Information about my environment**

- Mac OS Big Sur: 11.4
- VS for Mac: 8.10.6 (Build 10)
- Xamarin.Android: 11.3.0.4
- SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
- SDK Platform Tools Version: 31.0.2
- SDK Build Tools Version: 31.0.0 rc5
- microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25 1.8.0-25
- Xamarin.Forms: 5.0.0.2012
- Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material: 5.0.0.2012
- Xamarin.Google.Android.Material: 1.2.1.1

**Additional Information**

- Using AndroidX libraries
- No references to `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design`
- Cleaned Solution many times Manually
- Deleted All bin and obj folders multiple times and reset Visual Studio several Times
- Target Framework: 10.0 (Q)

**Issue:**
I was able to build and deploy to my device but when the app runs and loads a login page, during `InitializeComponent()` call, the following exception is thrown:

> ERROR: System.TypeLoadException: Parent class vtable failed to initialize, due to: VTable setup of type AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout failed assembly:/data/data/com.app.dev/files/.**override**/Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll type:SwipeRefreshLayout member:(null)
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.RuntimeTypeHandle.type_is_assignable_from(System.Type,System.Type)
> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CanCastTo (System.RuntimeType type, System.RuntimeType target) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System/RuntimeTypeHandle.cs:265
> at System.RuntimeType.IsAssignableFrom (System.Type c) [0x00020] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:3809
> at Xamarin.Forms.VisualTypeConverter.Register (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] mappings) [0x00019] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Visuals\VisualTypeConverter.cs:64
> at Xamarin.Forms.VisualTypeConverter.InitMappings () [0x0001a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Visuals\VisualTypeConverter.cs:22
> at Xamarin.Forms.VisualTypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString (System.String value) [0x00007] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Visuals\VisualTypeConverter.cs:119

Below is the xaml from the page being loaded:

```xml
<ContentPage x:Class="SignInPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:XF.Core.Effects;assembly=XF.Core"
            x:Name="SignInPage"
            IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            Visual="Material"
            mc:Ignorable="d">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout
            x:Name="ContentStackLayout"
            Margin="0"
            Padding="0"
            AutomationId="ContentStackLayout"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid
                x:Name="MainContentGrid"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                AutomationId="MainContentGrid"
                ColumnSpacing="0"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                RowSpacing="0"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition.Height>
                            <OnIdiom
                                x:TypeArguments="GridLength"
                                Phone="50"
                                Tablet="60" />
                        </RowDefinition.Height>
                    </RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image
                    x:Name="HeaderGradientImage"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                    Aspect="Fill"
                    AutomationId="HeaderGradientImage"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                    Source="{Binding HeaderGradientBackgroundImageUrl}"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill" />
                <Label
                    x:Name="TitleLabel"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                    AutomationId="TitleLabel"
                    Style="{Binding HeaderTitleWhiteLabelStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <Image
                    x:Name="LogoImage"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="4"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    AutomationId="LogoImage"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="{Binding LogoIconUrl}"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding AppLogoTappedCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <StackLayout
                    x:Name="SignInStackLayout"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                    AutomationId="SignInStackLayout"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout.VerticalOptions>
                        <OnIdiom
                            x:TypeArguments="LayoutOptions"
                            Phone="CenterAndExpand"
                            Tablet="StartAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout.VerticalOptions>
                    <StackLayout.Margin>
                        <OnIdiom
                            x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                            Phone="15,0,15,0"
                            Tablet="50,75,50,0" />
                    </StackLayout.Margin>
                    <Label
                        x:Name="PleaseLogInLabel"
                        Margin="0,7,0,0"
                        AutomationId="PleaseLogInLabel"
                        FontSize="Large"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Text="Please Log In"
                        TextColor="#002D72"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Label
                        x:Name="UserIdLabel"
                        Margin="0,15,0,0"
                        AutomationId="UserIdLabel"
                        FontSize="Small"
                        Text="USER ID"
                        TextColor="#002D72"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label.WidthRequest>
                            <OnIdiom
                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                Phone="200"
                                Tablet="320" />
                        </Label.WidthRequest>
                    </Label>
                    <Frame
                        x:Name="UserIdFrame"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        AutomationId="UserIdFrame"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        BorderColor="#002D72"
                        Padding="0,0,0,0">
                        <Entry
                            x:Name="UserIdEntry"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            AutomationId="UserIdEntry"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            Keyboard="Text"
                            Placeholder="User"
                            PlaceholderColor="#BBBBBB"
                            Text="{Binding UserId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            TextChanged="UserIdEntry_TextChanged"
                            TextColor="#002D72"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            Visual="Material">
                            <Entry.WidthRequest>
                                <OnIdiom
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    Phone="200"
                                    Tablet="320" />
                            </Entry.WidthRequest>
                            <Entry.Effects>
                                <effects:CgEntryCapitalizeKeyboardEffect />
                            </Entry.Effects>
                        </Entry>
                    </Frame>
                    <Label
                        x:Name="PasswordLabel"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        AutomationId="PasswordLabel"
                        FontSize="Small"
                        Text="Password"
                        TextColor="#002D72"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label.WidthRequest>
                            <OnIdiom
                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                Phone="200"
                                Tablet="320" />
                        </Label.WidthRequest>
                    </Label>
                    <Frame
                        x:Name="PasswordFrame"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        AutomationId="PasswordFrame"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        BorderColor="#002D72"
                        Padding="0,0,0,0">
                        <Entry
                            x:Name="PasswordEntry"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            AutomationId="PasswordEntry"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            IsPassword="true"
                            Keyboard="Text"
                            Placeholder="Desktop Password"
                            PlaceholderColor="#BBBBBB"
                            Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            TextChanged="PasswordEntry_TextChanged"
                            TextColor="#002D72"
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Entry.WidthRequest>
                                <OnIdiom
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    Phone="200"
                                    Tablet="320" />
                            </Entry.WidthRequest>
                        </Entry>
                    </Frame>
                    <Label
                        x:Name="DomainLabel"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        AutomationId="DomainLabel"
                        FontSize="Small"
                        Text="Domain"
                        TextColor="#002D72"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Label.WidthRequest>
                            <OnIdiom
                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                Phone="200"
                                Tablet="320" />
                        </Label.WidthRequest>
                    </Label>
                    <Frame
                        x:Name="NetworkDomainPickerFrame"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        AutomationId="NetworkDomainPickerFrame"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        BorderColor="#002D72"
                        Padding="0,0,0,0">
                        <Picker
                            x:Name="NetworkDomainPicker"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            AutomationId="NetworkDomainPicker"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            Title="Select Network Domain"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding NetworkDomainList}"
                            TitleColor="#BBBBBB"
                            SelectedIndexChanged="NetworkDomainPicker_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNetworkDomain, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            TextColor="#002D72"
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Picker.WidthRequest>
                                <OnIdiom
                                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    Phone="200"
                                    Tablet="320" />
                            </Picker.WidthRequest>
                        </Picker>
                    </Frame>
                    <Button
                        x:Name="SignInButton"
                        Margin="0,15,0,0"
                        AutomationId="SignInButton"
                        BackgroundColor="#056DAE"
                        Command="{Binding SignInCommand}"
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsFormEntryValid}"
                        Text="Log In"
                        TextColor="White">
                        <Button.HeightRequest>
                            <OnIdiom
                                x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                Phone="40"
                                Tablet="50" />
                        </Button.HeightRequest>
                    </Button>
                    <BoxView
                        x:Name="ViewHeaderSeparatorBoxView"
                        Margin="0,15,0,15"
                        AutomationId="ViewHeaderSeparatorBoxView"
                        BackgroundColor="#CCCCCC"
                        HeightRequest="2"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <ScrollView x:Name="DisclaimerScrollView" AutomationId="DisclaimerScrollView">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label
                                x:Name="DisclaimerLabel"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                AutomationId="DisclaimerLabel"
                                FontSize="Small"
                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                Text="{Binding SignInDisclaimerText}"
                                TextColor="#53565A"
                                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                            <Label
                                x:Name="DisclaimerLabel"
                                Margin="0,20,0,0"
                                AutomationId="DisclaimerLabel"
                                FontSize="Micro"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                Text="{Binding SignInDisclaimerText}"
                                TextColor="#53565A"
                                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 13):

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14424

Installing Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.AppCompatResources (version 1.3.0)

and downgrading

Xamarin.AndroidX.Core from version 1.6.0 to 1.5.0

solved the problem for me.

Comment: This solution is still valid as of 1/3/22.  Though I am using the latest version of AppCompatResources.

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is correct but incomplete. When one downgrades the Xamarin.AndroidX.Core from version 1.6.0 to 1.5.0, it causes incompatibility issues. to solve it, here are the downgrades I did to the other packages.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Installing Xamarin.AndroidX.SwipeRefreshLayout into our android project worked for us while maintaining Xamarin.AndroidX.Core 1.6.0.1.

See the GitHub thread here for more information: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14424.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by upgrading Xamarin.Forms to 5.0.0.2337.

Comment: I just needed to update Xamarin.Forms to the latest, to get it higher than version 5.0.0.2012.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue as well.  Discovered that all pages containing the ListView element would crash OnAppearing.

The other answers already stated seem to also get the job done.

**Solutions** which worked for me were:

- Utilizing a CollectionView instead.
- Or upgrading the Android target framework from v.10/11 to v.12
- &/or upgrading all AndroidX libraries within NuGet package manager to the latest (June 2022 release).  Updated Xamarin.Forms to 5.0.0.2478 (5.0.0 Service Release 11) as well.

Comment: Just upgrading the Android target framework from v10 to v12 did not fix this for me.